# Why is self.currentViewController nil in ViewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Recently changed which View in my project is the starting point (with the arrow pointing to it in IB), and now I get the following error when the app starts in the simulator:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The error occurs during the ViewDidLoad() of the view that ***used to be*** the starting point, but which isn't now.  Honestly, not even sure why it's loading, but that's not a part of Swift I know enough about to recognize if this view (also) loading at startup is expected or not.  The code where the error occurs is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    print("Former First View starts DidLoad")

    // Code to enable the containerView to work:
    self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SmallViewWithinMainView")
    self.currentViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
    // Error occurs in the next line:
    self.addSubview(subView: self.currentViewController!.view, toView: self.SortFilterEtcContainerView)

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...
```

With testing, self.currentViewController is in fact now nil, but I'm unclear how to fix the situation.  Before the change, when this view was where everything started, it ran fine.  What needs to happen so that self.currentViewController is no longer nil?

Comment: super.viewDidLoad() on top, seems the viewcontroller doesn't initialized.

Comment: If `self.currentViewController` is nil, I would expect your error to arise two lines earlier.  Are you sure it is `currentViewController` that is nil - or could it be `self.SortFilterEtcContainerView` that is nil?

Comment: @pbasdf  Added some code to check each thing individually, and it IS self.currentViewController which is nil, even from the outset.  Agree odd that the error doesn't show up until as late as it does.  What can make self.currentViewController be nil???

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) self.storyboard is nil; or 2) your identifier is wrong in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with xcode 9 and swift 3. 
I fixed it casting the ViewController in this way:

```
if let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReaIDController") as? DetalleIpadViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call

```
super.viewDidLoad()
```

At the very first line of your `viewDidLoad` function.

Then a proper fix would be to stop force unwrapping optionals

Before: **BAD**

```
// Code to enable the containerView to work:
self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SmallViewWithinMainView")
self.currentViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
```

After: **GOOD**

```
    // Code to enable the containerView to work:
        if let curView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SmallViewWithinMainView") {
            curView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.addChildViewController(curView)
        } else {
            // Error
        }
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but no help. Same line as before gets same error as before. NOTE that the code ran fine BEFORE I shifted which View gets the initial entry, so while the if let curView = ... is clearly good practice, neither it nor the super.viewDidLoad() where it was was causing an error before the shift.  And, the error seems to NOT be that "let curView..." was nil, but as @pbasdf suggested, the other -- the toView -- is nil. Because when I run the simluator now, the "// Error" isn't reached -- the same line just creates an error.